# Vertically center in viewport using CSS

Tags: css, layout, center, viewport, styling

I am looking to vertically center a `<div>` in the viewport (browser window) without resorting to Javascript (pure HTML and CSS only).  I have several constraints:

- **The `div` must be centered vertically in the viewport.**  Methods I have seen only support centering inside another `<div>`, which is not what I want.
- The height of the `div` is not known.

Other constraints:

- The `div` must be aligned to the right.
- The `div` has a constant width.
- The `div` must support padding.
- Other elements will be placed on the web page.  The `div` acts as a menu.
- The div must support a background colour/image.

This gets me close to what I want, but not exactly:

```
#nav {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
}
```

However, the *top* of the nav is in the middle, not the *middle* of the nav.

Is there some technique which allows me to center my `div` with these constraints?

Comment: This article might help: [http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html) I've used it before it seems to work in Safari/Firefox.

Comment: @Ólafur Waage, None of your edited-in dupes are duplicates of my issue.  That is, none of them resolve my issue.

Comment: @Adam Davis, I have updated my major constraint.

Comment: strager - please edit the question then.  Most of your problems are discussed in the other questions.  Try the solutions, then post a very specific question that focuses on the remaining problem(s)

Comment: Even better, post the code that gets you the closest, then ask the remaining issue.

Comment: @Adam Davis, Is this more clear?  (Thanks for your critiquing, by the way.)

Comment: strager - when you say centered vertically in the viewport, do you mean when you scroll the page up and down the div should never move from the dead middle of the screen?

Comment: @Paolo Bergantino, Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: I agree with the constraints after editing so i voted to reopen.

Comment: strager - Looks good.  Thanks for differentiating it from the others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use this as one of the solution.

```
   <style>
   #containter {
     height: 100vh; //vh - viewport height
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-items: center; 
     justify-content: center;
   }
   #content {}
  </style>

 <div id="containter">
  <div id="content">
    any text<br>
    any height<br>
    any content, for example generated from DB<br>
    everything is vertically centered
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 32):

What's that? Taking **8 years** to get the answer to a problem is too much?

Well, better late than never!

You got *really* close to the solution. I'd do it with [`transform: translate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transform#translate()):

```
#nav {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

According to [Can I use?](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d), it is supported by everything except for IE8- and Opera Mini (which, to be honest, is a pretty good support).

I'd recommend you overkill it a bit and just add all of the vendor prefixes (just to make sure!):

```
#nav {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;

    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
       -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
         -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Here's a snippet to show it to you in action:

```css
#nav {
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
       -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
         -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateY(-50%);

    background-color: #ccc;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
    ABC<br/>
    DEFGH<br/>
    IJKLMNO<br/>
    PQRS<br/>
    TUVWXYZ
</div>
```

Hopefully it's still relevant to you! (who am I kidding, it's been *8 years*)

Comment: This is good, but still not perfect. There are numerous issues with `transform` that I've experienced first-hand, including but not limited to: 1. images in the centered div can become blurry (no easy fix), 2. it breaks some plugins like REDIPS.drag. The `table-cell` technique solves the two issues above, but it introduces a new issue: it's centered relative to the initial viewport, not the viewport you are currently in after scrolling.

Answer (score 3):

> If the item is set to `position: fixed` or `position: absolute`:
>
> ```
> top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
> ```
>
> If the item is set to `position: relative`, use:
>
> ```
> margin-top: 50%; margin-left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
> ```

(More info at [the source](https://www.inflectra.com/support/knowledgebase/kb234.aspx).)

---

### Example:

Run the snippet and then resize this page (or rotate device). The box stays centered in the "snippet viewport".

```css
.myContainer {  
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 5px solid RebeccaPurple;
}

.myThing {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: CornflowerBlue;
}
```

```html
<div class="myContainer">
  <div class="myThing myContents">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is not to use a `div` - use a `table` with one row and one cell.  Vertical alignment is woefully unsupported in CSS and you will find yourself coding up the wall and across the ceiling to accomplish it.

I understand the semantic argument against what I have just proposed - I am a proponent of semantic markup in most cases.  However I also believe in using the right tool for the right job.  I believe it is best to sacrifice a little purity in this case for a simple solution that will work.

Comment: Read my first constraint, please.  How would this solve that problem?

Comment: Tables are nothing special. In Standards Mode, setting height on a table has exactly the same effect as setting height on a div. Only Quirks Mode sizes table height relative to the viewport by default; you can get this behaviour in Standards Mode by setting ‘height: 100%’ on every ancestor element.

Comment: From an accessibility point of view tables while convenient for layout really get in the way of the operation of screen-readers.  Yes you can mitigate this to some degree by marking the table as having role="presentation" - but the purpose of tables is to present tabular data.

Comment: In 2013 this is not good advice. Future readers should not do this.

Comment: The real solution, I believe, is to use semantic elements wherever possible and admit when it is NOT.  A whole bunch of CSS tweaking with many comments to even give a chance to understand will NEVER make your site more maintainable, more semantic, more modern. Accept the imperfection of the current state of HTML. Please. Hide the mess but accept that it's necessary, esp in this very case.