# Make a div center of viewport - Horizontally and vertically

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a `<div id="wrapper">` container in which my whole site content will be present. I have tried to make the div center vertically and horizontally by using css property like `margin:0 auto; on #wrapper`.

```
#wrapper
{
 width:500px;
 height:500px;
 margin:0 auto;
 background:#f7f7f7;
}
```

By using above css i can make the div in (top center) of screen but how to make it center(vertically). when i zoom out in firefox my div is going to zoom out in top center but what i want it should be always present in the center of screen from both vertically and horizontally.

Can any one suggest me how can i get the layout like that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659677/vertically-center-in-viewport-using-css/42204490#42204490

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
#wrapper
{
 width:500px;
 height:500px;
 margin:0 auto;
 background:#f7f7f7;
 position:absolute;
 left:50%;
 top:50%;
 margin-left:-250px;
 margin-top:-250px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fJtNQ/

**Why is this working?**

Well, basically you have an absolute positioned element inside the dom. It means that you can position it wherever you want and if you don't have a relative positioned element as parent, left and top will be the distance from the document's left/top origin.

Assigning `left:50%` and `top:50%` enables this element to be positioned always in the center of the screen, but in the center you will find the top left corner of the element.

If you have fixed width/height, you can easily 'translate' the point in the center to be actually the center of the wrapper div by giving negative `margin-left` and `margin-top` (therefore with the help of some extremely easy basic math their values will be `-(width/2)` and `-(height/2)`)

**EDIT**

You can also easily center by using `flexbox`, plus (a big one) you don't need to specify w/h, i.e.:

```
body { /* can also be whatever container */
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#wrapper {
  /* whatever style u want */
}
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/00utf52o/

Comment: In the past, I've used methods where I've put the wrapper into another container element. Centering the outer vertically and the inner horizontally. This is much nicer.

Comment: I normally don't like when people just post a JSFiddle and the code without an explanation just to be the fastest to answer, but it is a good answer, +1

Comment: U're right, I was with mobile, and as far as the solution was pretty straightforward I just answered it in 1 sec. Gonna explain it asap :)

Comment: @stecb Remember, just because he accepted it doesn't mean you shouldn't explain what's going on. At least put in a link to a tutorial that does vertical alignment. It's good to have references. ;)

Comment: that's a way that works, however it is not recommended as best practice, because if your viewport is smaller than the element you center you will not see the whole element and you won't be able to scroll! So, be careful with this! Better is to use margin:auto, e.g.

Comment: ** If you have fixed width/height ... ** Is there a way to do this for varying heights. I am trying to position an image vertically center and with 100% width in mobile responsive views.

Comment: @dreamster yep u can, by using flexbox is pretty straightforward: http://jsfiddle.net/6wb420m0/2/

Comment: @stecb but that stretches the image. I found a solution. Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34084294/2733146

Comment: @dreamster ah I got what u meant. Do also a fiddle ;)

Comment: 2018 update: just used the flexbox method and it works just fine. This should be the solution in almost all cases in my opinion.

Answer (score 41):

@stecb's answer works fine if you're working with fixed width/height.

To position a div or an image vertically at the center in all viewports and make it responsive, use this:

```
#elem-to-center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

I just replaced margin-left and margin-top with transform.

If you want a margin surrounding the element, use this:

```
#outer-elem {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 30px;
    background: #fafafa;
    position: relative;
}
#elem-to-center {
    width: calc(100% - 60px);
    max-height: calc(100% - 60px);

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ugqwkn0/2/) | 
[Source](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html#vertical3)

I found this useful even in responsive views.

Comment: `#elem-to-center` works very well for large viewports. But it breaks for smaller viewports. How can this solution be translated to smaller viewports?

Comment: @GitauHarrison I just checked the JSFiddle and couldn't reproduce. Maybe your styling is different. Can you please briefly explain what exactly you are trying to achieve? A fiddle will help.

Answer (score 17):

Here is a solution for those who need to center a child div relative to viewport and not "relative to parent div". Other solutions mentioned here do not work in this case as they tend to make the child div center relative to the parent div.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="wrapper">Always center, No matter the parent div's position</div>
</div>

#wrapper {
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 margin:0 auto;
 background:green;
 position:fixed;
 left:50%;
 top:50%;
 margin-left:-150px;
 margin-top:-150px;
}

#container {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

demo here http://jsbin.com/yeboleli/2/edit?css,output

Comment: When I open your demo for me the `wrapper` element is not centered vertically, but only horizontally.

Comment: Position fixed was the way to go, the other solutions didn't work as you mentioned, since they don't implement it according teh the viewport.

Answer (score 2):

I use jQuery

```
$(window).resize(function(){

    $('.className').css({
        position:'absolute',
        left: ($(window).width() - $('.className').outerWidth())/2,
        top: ($(window).height() - $('.className').outerHeight())/2
    });

});

// To initially run the function:
$(window).resize();
```

Comment: Using JavaScript when u can solve problems by css only should be always avoided.

Comment: @stecb Not only is it something to be avoided, but it also makes you look uncool. CSS has always been for the cool kids.

Comment: So should shortening the word "you". Using CSS for something that may be dynamic and cannot be solved through CSS should be avoided. Sure, I could center a square too... but if that square becomes something different...

Comment: That's another problem :P ..this is a general solution for the case of an element with fixed w/h. If different cases can't be solved by css I'd prefer to change the layout instead of opting for JS (that IMO shouldn't be used to solve layout problems).

Comment: The CSS solution requires that you know the width and height of the element.  In responsive layouts the width and height of an element changes.

Comment: To add to this.. if you want to properly vertically center elm to viewport regardless of scroll position you need to take into account their current vertical scroll position and add that to the top value.

    top: $('.elm').css('top', ($(window).height() - $(elm).outerHeight())/2 + $(window).scrollTop())

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and the cleanest way to do this would be by setting the height, margin (and width, if you want) using viewport sizes. 
Say you want the `height` of you container to occupy 60% (60vh) of the screen, you can divide the rest (40vh, since total height of the viewport = 100vh) equally between the top and the bottom margin so that the element aligns itself in the centre automatically.
Setting the `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `auto`, will make sure the container is centred horizontally.

```css
.container {
         width: 60vw; /*optional*/
         height: 60vh;
         margin: 20vh auto;
         background: #333;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

---

Consider using `display: table` coupled with `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle` on a separate element. Because CSS does not have semantic meaning, it's an acceptable solution.

I worked up an example for you: http://dabblet.com/gist/2002681

The only downside is that requires a little more markup than some other solutions, but it contracts and expands with the content.