# creating separate rules for horizontal and vertical alignment in css

Tags: css

The plunkr link is https://plnkr.co/edit/mv3lL1vwu2LxoeFZw0TX

I want to position a `div` at the center of a page (vertically and horizontally). The `div` has a button which should be at the center of the `div`. I found a solution in [Vertically center in viewport using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659677/vertically-center-in-viewport-using-css) but it doesn't work for me. Also, I want to create two separate rules, one for vertical alignment and one for horizontal alignment and use them together (or separately) so that I can pick which element should be aligned in which way.

I do not want to use Flex, Bootstrap etc. as I am trying to understand CSS concepts.

the horizontal alignment rule is straightforward.

```
.center-horizontally-common-styles {
    display: block;
    margin: auto auto;
}
```

The vertical alignment rule is (modified from the SO link)

```
.centre-vertical-common-styles {
   position: fixed;
    right: 50%; 
    top: 50%; 
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(50%);
}


.debug-border-common-styles {
    border: 3px solid black;
    height:40px;
    width:200px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="debug-border-common-styles centre-vertical-common-styles center-horizontally-common-styles">
    <button type="button"> Click Me! </button>
</div>
```

My understanding is that `right: 50%; top: 50%;` will use the browser's window (viewport?) as the reference and move the `div`'s top edge and right edge to the location which is 50% mark of the browser's respective edge's location. `TranslateY` and `TranslateX` should now move the `div` upwards (-50%) and towards left(50%) respectively to align the button's center to the middle of the page thus centering the button. The issues I am facing are:

1) The `translateY` doesn't seem to work. If I change the height of the `div` to say 200px. the `div` starts growing downwards (i.e. its top edge seem to be fixed!) It doesn't happen if the width is changed to say 200px.

```
.debug-border-common-styles {
    border: 3px solid black;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
}
```

2) The button inside the `div` is not at the center of the div. I created the following `css` rule for the button but translateY doesn't seem to work on this one as well.

```
.centre-button-vertical-common-styles {
   position: absolute; /*use absolute so that the origin is no the parent div*/
   right: 50%; 
   top: 50%; 
   transform: translateY(-50%);
   transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

3) Ideally, I would like to create two separate rules, say .center-vertical and .center-horizontal and combine them to use the desired effect. But If I do something like follows, it doesn't work. Is it possible to create two separate rules?

```
.center-horizontally-common-styles {
    display: block;
    margin: auto auto;
}
```

Not use right here because horizontal rule should place the item in middle

```
.centre-button-vertical-common-styles {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%; 
   transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: In CSS properties can have only 1 value - so your `transform:translateY(-50%);` is overwritten with `transform:translateX(50%);`

Comment: Thanks. How could I then move an element both horizontally and vertically?

Comment: You can add new class for horizontal _and_ vertical centering. Or you can try using flexbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bro, you need few arrows of style. Do like this:)

```
 .centre-vertical-common-styles {
       position: fixed;
        left: 50%; 
        top: 50%; 
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    .debug-border-common-styles {
        border: 3px solid black;
        height:40px;
        width:200px;
        display:flex;
        align-items:center;
        justify-content:center;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I think you meant `transform: translate(50%, -50%);`. Only adding `transform: translate(50%, -50%);` was sufficient (https://plnkr.co/edit/mv3lL1vwu2LxoeFZw0TX), what is the purpose of `display:flex;  align-items:center;   justify-content:center;`

Comment: All childs elements of block, that have display:flex; align-items:center; justify-content:center; will  be align center without any styles.

Comment: I tried that on plunkr. It doesn't work well. Adding translate to both div and button seem to position things better than using flex. See here - https://plnkr.co/edit/mv3lL1vwu2LxoeFZw0TX

Comment: apologies, you are correct. So I could use your solution and remove the class `centre-button-vertical-common-styles` from button or I could use my original solution and use `translate` instead of `translateX/translateY` because of the issue mentioned by fex1x

Comment: from browser support perspective, is `translate` better than `flex`?